# Excel-VBA Get Code of the design of existing cells

Tags: excel, vba

For an application of protocolling some measurements and therefore made a design for the print out of the data. This is a fairly complex design with many highlighted area, marked cells, font size changes, background color, pictures and so on.

My question is: Is there any way to get the design as a VBA code to "store" it without doing it all manually?

I already tried around some with the macro, though I couldn't "read" the current cell design.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question is too vague. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Just copying the format to another sheet? Or something else?

Comment: I do have a variing page I want to print and by selecting the specific option I'd like to transform the sheet "Print" into the format of my template. Because I have 16 templates later on I don't want to have them shown all the way, therefore intending to save/store the template as code only in order to later on use it, if selected.

Comment: You should look into the Range object in VBA which gives you access to properties such as font, borders, alignment, etc. So, for example, Range("A1").Font.Bold = True

Comment: You could save your empty templates on hidden sheets and copy the required on to the "print" sheet.   Storing all of the formatting in code will be difficult to manage unless it's very basic formatting.

Comment: @Tim Williams, got the same idea while rewriting my question and probably gonna do that, though I still have to figure out some smaller flaws that aren't done the way I want/need it. If you're interested in it, write it as an answer and not as a comment so I can mark it.

Comment: You could record a macro while you do the setup. This generates VBA code that you can edit or 'tweak' as required. (See: [**Recording a Macro to Generate Code**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code) as well as [**Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros))

Comment: @ashleedawg The problem I'm facing is that it would take me extremly long to redo the design while recording it as a makro. I  would need a way to basicly just select the cells and have the details. Because I already have the design I will be going to use the answer provided by Tim Williams. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save your empty templates on hidden sheets and copy the required on to the "print" sheet. Storing all of the formatting in code will be difficult to manage unless it's very basic formatting.